# How to resize a Gtk.Image in vala

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm trying to resize a Image in vala.
So I read valadoc and end up writing this code

```
var img = new Gtk.Image.from_file ("fire.png");

var pix_buf = img.get_pixbuf ();
pix_buf.scale_simple (50, 50, InterpType.BILINEAR);

window.add (img);
```

But it has no effect.

If there is a way to dynamically scale the image so that it fill his container it would be awesome, but just scaling it would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Pixbuf.scale_simple`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gdk-pixbuf-2.0/Gdk.Pixbuf.scale_simple) does not modify the image. It returns a new `Pixbuf` that has been scaled. Use [`Image.from_pixbuf`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Image.Image.from_pixbuf) to create a new image and add that to your window.