# Vala GTK - How to resize image

Tags: gtk, vala

This is my code:

```
Gtk.Image logo = new Gtk.Image();
logo.set_from_file("./img.png");
logo.pixel_size = 10;
```

It doesn't work. How can I properly resize an image with Vala?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should edit your question to add a bit more description of what exactly you want to achieve. The way it stands your question is too short and does not show enough research effort.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099740/how-to-resize-a-gtk-image-in-vala?rq=1

Comment: `pixel_size` only works for named icons (e.g. help-about ), for arbitrary images you will have to scale the pixbuf as suggested by Jens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize a Gtk.Image in vala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099740/how-to-resize-a-gtk-image-in-vala)